# Convert multiple MediaStreams into 1 stream

Tags: javascript, webrtc, getusermedia

I want to convert 2 different MediaStreams into 1 MediaStream. For example: You have a moving text stream and I want to overlay this on a webcam stream. How would I be able to do this?

Some things to take into consideration:
- I want to 'burn' the moving text on top of the webcam
- No multiple videotracks
- I'd rather not use toDataURL or render on canvas and then convert to 1 stream since this is a huge CPU hog.

Comment: You could attach the media streams to two seperate video elements and then absolute position them on top of each other.

Comment: I do not want to use multiple media streams as noted in my question. My application needs to specifically use 1 stream to minimise the bandwidth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer depends on features not yet implemented and for which the spec is still to-be-written:
1) get video and text stream
2) use webgl to merge the text stream onto the video background (I presume webgl has stuff that can do this; effectively it's a green-screen technique
3) dump the webgl frames to a canvas
4)** get a mediastream from the canvas via canvas.captureStream() -- note, no implementations exist for this yet, and the spec isn't even written, though we all agree it's a good thing

Alternatively: if it's truly text, ship it in parallel over a DataChannel and render it at the receiver side into a text overlay of the .  This will work today and be much more efficient.  Bandwidth for the text will be minimal.